# Open project in XCode using Foodomia.xcworkspace file

Tags: xcode

I am installing a source code into xcode, however, it says to first open the project using the "Foodomia.xcworkspace" file. Where can I access the Foodomia.xcworkspace file in Xcode?

Thank You!

Comment: What does the folder look like in which your project is located?

Answer (score 0):

On the .xcodeproj file, right click > show package contents. Workspace file(s) will be in there.

Comment: Hi, I am on the project, however, I do not see the “Show Package Contents” section. I have attached a picture. 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/dalyidrr4kfp2xn/Photo%20Sep%2028%2C%202%2036%2016%20PM.jpg?dl=0

Comment: I mean do that in Finder. Right click on the project file in Finder